# Expectation of function of random variable with at most countable range

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

I am working through Oksendal's SDE book and my answer is slightly different to the solution found online. I was wondering if my solution is correct. This is exercise 2.1(d).

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space on which a (real-valued) random variable $X$ is defined. Assume that the range of $X$ is countable, e.g. $X$ takes values in $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$.

**Exercise:** If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and measurable, show that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}f(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(a_k) P(X = a_k)
\end{equation}

**My Solution:**
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}f(X) &= \int_\Omega f(X) P(dw) \\
    &= \int_\Omega f(X) \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}}  P(dw)
\end{align}
since the pre-images $\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}$ partition $\Omega$. Then bounded convegence can be used since
\begin{equation}
   \lvert f(X) \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}} \rvert \leq M
\end{equation}
for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ since $f$ is bounded. So
\begin{align}
    \int_\Omega \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg( f(X) \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}}\bigg)  P(dw) &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\Omega f(X) \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}}  P(dw) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_\Omega f(X) 1_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}}  P(dw) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\{X^{-1}(a_k)\}} f(X)  P(dw) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(a_k) P(X=a_k),
\end{align}
as desired. Is my proof correct or have I made some mistakes? Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice proof! The notation is a bit weird to me in that $X$ is appearing in the integrand but the measure you are integrating against does not reference $X$ but instead $\omega$, e.g. I would expect to see $\int f(X)dP_X$, or $\int f(\omega)dP(\omega)$, but it is clear what it means!

Comment: Thanks, sorry about notation! $X$ is dependent on $\omega$, i.e. $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\omega \mapsto X(\omega)$.